# What's the term for the text in a published module intended to be read aloud to the PCs?

Tags: published-adventures, terminology

Is there a defined, standard, or "industry" term used by module publishers for the text in a  module (or adventure) that is done in a shaded background and intended to be read aloud to the players?

As an example, I'm holding a copy of [Lord of the Iron Fortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_Iron_Fortress).  On page two it says:

> In the adventure itself, the shaded boxes provide player information
>   for you to paraphrase or read aloud when appropriate.

An example of that type of text from page six of the same module reads in part:

> Four soldiers led by a fair-skinned officer stride across the street
>   toward you, a determined look in their eyes.

I know *what* the text is used for.  What I'm wondering is if there is a standard **term** for that type of information.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This has been called simply **boxed text** for decades, even when not literally typeset in a box. Not a very interesting name!

Comment: It might be worth noting it's called boxed text because all those early D&D modules (and other TSR games like Star Frontiers, etc. ) used a bordered box to set it apart from the rest of the adventure text.  Other games weren't as formative here because most of them didn't concentrate on publishing adventures.

Comment: In fact doing some searching, the term "boxed text" is actually used in the text of many early D&D adventures, especially RPGA tournament modules that turned into the classic line of 1e AD&D adventures - like A3 "The boxed text is material which should be read to the players as they approach that area..."  In fact, as early as 1981 in Basic D&D  module X1 it says "You may read the following boxed text to the players..." when there's not an actual box used around the read-aloud text in the adventure - the term had therefore been completely genericized by this time.

Comment: @mxyzplk Nice references! Want to edit those in? I was going to pull out some modules later to track down exactly that sort of stuff — quotes and dates — but I'm still on mobile and away from my collection.

Comment: Side Note: In german it is called "Vorlesetext", which translates roughly to "text you read out loud". Not that much better :D